# how to multiply each element in an array with a loop c#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

im trying to multiply each element in three different arrays by 2 with a loop but im having trouble. im really new at this so please excuse any obvious mistakes lol im not even sure ive im using the right kind of loop but heres what i have so far:

```
int[] firstArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 5, 6, 9 };
int[] secondArray = new int[] { 12, 3, 8, 20, 7 };
int[] thirdArray = new int[] { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 };

  foreach(new int [5] in firstArray)
{
   int newArray1= firstArray.Length * 2;
    Console.WriteLine(newArray1);
}
```

i want it to print out the first new array as "2, 4, 10, 12, 18" in the console but when i run it, i get the error type and identifier are both required in a foreach statement.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is `secondArray` and `thirdArray` here?

Comment: I was looking at this code and thinking.... surely that code doesn't compile. And no it doesn't compile....  foreach expects a variable where you have "new int[5]" e.g. "foreach(int tempVariable in firstArray)" it loops through the array placing each consecutive member in the tempVariable.

Comment: Get yourself a copy of the C# specification and take a look at the MSDN documentation. Simple questions like "what's the correct syntax for a foreach loop" can be answered by you reading the documentation.

Comment: Both the answers below are correct.  I would advise you to make sure you understand marc's answer before considering using linq which is a framework which internally implements as marc has illustrated.

Answer (score 4):

Do this with `Linq`

```
int[] resultFirstArray = firstArray.Select(r=> r * 2).ToArray();
int[] resultSecondArray = secondArray.Select(r=> r * 2).ToArray();
int[] resultThirdArray = thirdArray.Select(r=> r * 2).ToArray();
```

Or you can use `Array.ConvertAll`

> Array.ConvertAll converts an entire array. It converts all elements in one array to another type.

```
var resultFirstArray = Array.ConvertAll(firstArray, x => 2 * x);
var resultSecondArray = Array.ConvertAll(secondArray, x => 2 * x);
var resultThirdArray = Array.ConvertAll(thirdArray, x => 2 * x);
```

Comment: A good answer, but clearly this person probably needs to start with the basics before moving on to frameworks which circumvent them.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to show the doubled values:

```
foreach(int value in firstArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(2 * value);
}
```

If you want to double the values *in* the array, then:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < firstArray.Length ; i++)
{
    firstArray[i] *= 2;
}
```

Then perhaps to show those values:

```
foreach(int value in firstArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

If you want to create a new array with the values doubled:

```
var doubledArray = Array.ConvertAll(firstArray, x => 2 * x);
```

And to output those values:

```
foreach(int value in doubledArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```